# Unprotected Windows Shares Still Requiring Password in Linux Mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, windows, samba, nemo

I am trying to access my windows shares from linux mint.

I have 2 windows computers (both Win 10) and my laptop on Linux Mint.

My office PC is password protected and can access those files from my laptop and Loung PC by entering the username and password for that PC.

My Lounge PC is open, however, password protected sharing is turned off. I can access the shares from the Office PC but on my laptop it prompts me for username (required), domain (required, default 'WORKGROUP) and password.

Entering the username alone for the Lounge PC doesn't work and I don't have a password set to enter in the password field.

I have tried reinstalling Linux Mint, adding `name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and restarting samba.

Does anyone know how to access windows unprotected network locations without being prompted for a username and password from Nemo?

Comment: https://techjourney.net/cannot-connect-to-cifs-smb-samba-network-shares-shared-folders-in-windows-10/

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks, didn't work though...